# Filter search based on selected drop downs in PHP

Tags: php, search, get

I have a Search form to search products.

```
<form method="get" action="search.php">
<select name="minprice">
  <option value="">Min price</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
  <option value="200">200</option>
  <option value="300">300</option>
  <option value="400">400</option>
  <option value="500">500</option>
</select>
  <select name="maxprice">
  <option value="">Max price</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
  <option value="200">200</option>
  <option value="300">300</option>
  <option value="400">400</option>
  <option value="500">500</option>
</select>
<select name="type">
  <option value="">type</option>
  <option value="electric">electric</option>
  <option value="other">other</option>
</select>
 <select name="brand">
  <option value="">type</option>
  <option value="asus">ASUS</option>
  <option value="ms">MS</option>
  <option value="other">other</option>
</select>
 <input type="submit" name="search" value="search">
 </form>
```

In `search.php` page, i need results based only on what selected.

If i selected single list, i need that result only.

Example : I selected `min price`=100 , then i need to select products with minimum price 100 only...

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28817916/filtering-results-based-on-dropdown-paramenters-using-php-mysql) method , but it is not easy in my case, i am sure there is another way to implement this.

Any experts??

Any help / Ideas greatly appreciated..

**EDIT**

```
if(isset($_GET['minprice'])
 {
   $minprice=$_GET['minprice'];
  $query="SELECT * FROM products WHERE price>='$minprice'";
  }
  else if()....
   {   }
```

I am currently doing this way, But on next conditions not taking...

My Questions:

1. Do only this way to get the results?
2. Any change needed on `$_GET['']` method like `!=""` or `empty()`.

Comment: Do you want this to happen dynamically or when the form is submitted?  If you want it when the form is submitted, what problem are you encountering with retrieving the selected values from POST and using them in your query?  If you want it dynamically, what issue are you having with your AJAX syntax?

Comment: are you doing the fitler on a database ? or just in the client side ?

Comment: @devlincarnate : not dynamic, only when submit , submitting form goes to search.php and there i need show results based on what i selected only...

Comment: See my edits @devlincarnate and KubiRoazhon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, change your form from get to post.  While users can manipulate POST, it's far easier to manipulate GET.

```
<form method="post" action="search.php">
```

Second, evaluate all of the POST variables first, and then compose your database query.

```
$minprice = isset($_POST['minprice']) ? $_POST['minprice'] : null;
$maxprice = isset($_POST['maxprice']) ? $_POST['maxprice'] : null;
$type = isset($_POST['type']) ? $_POST['type'] : null;
$brand = isset($_POST['brand']) ? $_POST['brand'] : null;
```

**NOTE:**  I'm not sure what database type you're using, but you should use [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) with these variables when building your query.  It's also a good idea to limit the possible values in your variables -- so, for example, if you expect price to always be a decimal number, you should cast the string to float.

You can then use something like the following for your query.  I'm going to assume you're using a mysql database.

```
"SELECT <columns> FROM products WHERE minprice >= ISNULL(<$minprice variable>,minprice) AND maxprice <= ISNULL(<$maxprice variable>,maxprice) AND type = ISNULL(<$type variable>,type) AND brand = ISNULL(<$brand variable>,brand)"
```

**NOTE:**  the query above needs to be changed to handle parameter binding / prepared statements.  Since I don't know your database flavor, I've given you the basic query structure.  Also, you should SELECT the specific columns you need from your table, not `SELECT *` (which is a performance hit).